# I opened 1 Heart & my partner promptly responded 2 NT. How many points does my partner have & what is the shape of his hand?

Tags: bridge

I opened 1 Heart & my partner promptly responded 2 NT.  How many points does my partner have & what is the shape of his hand?

Answer (score 4):

As with any bidding question, this depends on your partnership agreements. Without discussion, in the US I'd assume this is Jacoby 2NT (see for example [the Standard American Yellow Card booklet](https://web2.acbl.org/documentlibrary/play/SP3%20(bk)%20single%20pages.pdf)). Partner shows four hearts and game-forcing values.

With a good five-card side suit, bid it at the 4 level. Otherwise, with a short suit (singleton or void), bid it at the 3 level. Otherwise, with a minimum bid 4H, with some extras (15-17) bid 3NT, or with significant extras (18+) bid 3H.

Comment: Just to outline various alternatives: most experts play other variants of Jacoby 2N with a more complicated set of responses and or a lower minimum strength (but usually still 4+ hearts) for responder.  Some players, mostly novices who haven't learned Jacoby 2N but also some experts who prefer alternatives to Jacoby 2N, play 2N as showing a balanced hand, either agreed to be invitational (about 10-12) or agreed to be game forcing (12+ or so) or agreed to be stronger (15+ or so - this is sometimes called Baron).  There are yet other more exotic alternative agreements.